# LED from Arduino board doesn't switch off using the click of a button

Tags: button, arduino, arduino-uno, led

So I've been busy dealing with my programming homework during the afternoon, and I cannot seem to solve the issue in the code found below.

The exercise is that I need to toggle a LED by the press of a button. In my code, the LED goes on when I click the button, but it doesn't turn off when I click the button again.

```cpp
int pinButton = 5;
int LED = 10;
int currentState;
int previousState;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(pinButton, INPUT);
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
}

void toggleLed(){
  if (previousState == 1 && currentState == 0){

    digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
    Serial.println(currentState);
    Serial.println(previousState);
    delay(100);

  } else {

    digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
    Serial.println(currentState);
    Serial.println(previousState);
    delay(100);

  }
}

void loop() {

int currentState = digitalRead(pinButton);

if (currentState == 0 && previousState == 1) {

  Serial.println("Knop is losgelaten");

  toggleLed();

} 

previousState = currentState;

}
```

I guess that in the first if statement the else code block doesn't make sense, because in this case `previousState` and `currentState` will always be 1 and 0 respectively.

Do you guys have any tips?

This Arduino is an Arduino Uno by the way.

Answer (score 1):

I can see in your code, that you are not switching the light off again after you pressed the Button. It would have gone off if you would have put the if statement into a "while" statement.

Comment: Putting it into a 'while'-statement doesn't work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: Expanded on most points to address the additional questions in the comments.

1. You have two different variables named `currentState`, a global one and one local to `loop()`.  The global one is defined near the top of the program, not inside another function.  In `loop()`, you start with this line:

   `int currentState = digitalRead(pinButton);`

   Because you've included the `int` there, this actually creates a second variable that happens to have the same name as the global one.  The values of the two versions of `currentState` can change independently.  Within `loop()`, every time you reference `currentState`, you'll be referencing the local copy. Everywhere else (like in `toggleLed`) will be referencing the global copy.  If you just wanted to set the global one (which is what I assume you meant to do), then you need to drop the `int`:

   `currentState = digitalRead(pinButton);`

   This will change the global version of `currentState` without creating a new one.
2. You're not doing any debouncing, so you could see sporadic results depending upon the type of button.  With many buttons and switches, the transition between on and off can be noisy.  Debouncing filters out that noise.  **Edit**:  The delay in `toggleLed()` is probably sufficient to debounce, but usually debouncing is done *before* responding to a state change.
3. You should probably initialize `previousState`.  Since it's a global, and globals have static storage duration, and it's not otherwise initialized, the system will ensure that it's initialized to 0.  Explicit initialization would be more obvious to anyone who has to read the code, especially if they don't know all the rules of C as well.  Also, you probably want to initialize it to `LOW` rather than `0`.  Which leads to my final point.
4. The return value of `digitalRead()` is `HIGH` or `LOW`.  On the Uno, it probably doesn't matter that you use `1` or `0` instead of `HIGH` or `LOW`, but I believe it might matter if you ever port your code to certain other boards.  The `HIGH` and `LOW` constants exist to hide details, but that helps only if you use them consistently.  Using `HIGH` and `LOW` some of the time and `1` and `0` other times just makes it harder for people to understand your code, and it might cause portability problems if you ever want to try your code on a different board.

Comment: Thank you Adrion, for the elaborate reply. However, I do not follow you on some points you suggest. previousState is initialized at the very top of the code, right? HIGH or LOW don't matter on the Uno, we can also use 1's and 0's. Could you explain a little bit more about what you mean with your first statement? I'm still a little new to it all. I've heard about local int's and global int's, but I don't understand how that works. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I've expanded the answer to address your additional questions.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve that by reading the state of the pin defined as 'LED'. If it is in a HIGH state, turn it LOw and vice versa.

```
void toggleLed(){
// check if pin state is low, turn it on
if (digitalRead(LED) == 0)
digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
} else {
digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
 }
}
```